# Save and retrieve rupees symbol (₹ ) in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a database which is already designed by other developer for UK country and there are a number of `Varchar()` columns that contains the pound symbol. 
Now i have to change the pound symbol to rupees symbol for varchar columns.

One option is i will change varchar columns to `nvarchar()` and use the `unicode`. but this will be a lengthy process because I have more than 200 tables and a number of columns that may contains pound symbol.

Can anyone suggest any other solution for me to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rupee is a unicode symbol, so you just can't store it in `varchar` column. 
Every character not in codepage of your server will be converted into `?` symbol when being stored in `varchar` column.

The only way to accomplish your task - is change column type to `nvarchar` and update pound symbol to rupee one. There is no other solution.